# WordPress : Add locally hosted video in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am doing a WordPress site where i need to add a video link in a sidebar widget   , now for testing  purpose if i don't upload video and just host it locally using `WAMP`how can i link it in my widget ? Can someone please help me about it?

Comment: Surely it'll work in exactly the same as if it were hosted on a webserver? You just change the `src` value. How are you intending on displaying the video? HTML5 or using jQuery like FlowPlayer etc?

Answer (score 0):

If you uploaded it to the media library on the production server it obviously won't be available in your development environment.

You may need to add it locally as well for testing, although you won't need to upload the same video but you could use a smaller one to mimic behaviour.